# Ruby format.json add text to model column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I would like to add some text to a model when the json object is returned.  For example

```
format.json { render :json => @user.to_json, :status => 200 }
```

The @user model contains a field called website.  The user websites are in the format www.mysite.com, but I want the resulting json to display http://www.mymysite.com.

For example, there could be thousands of users.

```
@users = User.all  
format.json { render :json => @users.to_json, :status => 200 }
```

I don't want to go through all the users and update the website column one by one.  Is there a way to define this in the model where the returned value of website is http:// + self.website?

The more I research this it looks like I would override the method def as_json(options = {}), but I'm not sure how to do it to modify the website field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a method like the following in your `User` model class (`app/model/user.rb`):

```
def website_with_protocol
  "http://#{self.website}"
end
```

Then, you will be able to do: `@user.website_with_protocol` to get the user's website with `http://` in the beginning.

Or, if you don't mind, you can override the `website` column in your database by defining a `website` method in the model class like this:

```
def website
  "http://#{self.read_attribute(:website)}"
end
```

So, now if you call: `@user.website`, then it will give you something like this: `http://www.mymysite.com` as the `website` is overridden in the model class.

**P.S. Use the [read_attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Read.html#method-i-_read_attribute) method to read the `website` value in database.**